# Manipulating data of Mat in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have a vector of integers. I want to add this vector to a particular row/column in the Mat object. Is this possible. I have been looking at the API and am unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`cv::Mat::row()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-row) and `cv::Mat::col()`.

Comment: again, careful with col(), as you're not manipulating the underlying buffer, but a copy!

Comment: um, the documentation of method says something else. It returns a header with data in the original matrix. There maybe problems when assigning some in one matrix, but that is not the case. Just to be sure, [`cv::Mat::copyTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) can be used.

Comment: awww, you made me think again. should have made a testcase, before typing an answer. mea culpa!.  also, since i can't downvote my own answer, would you do that for me, please?

Answer (score 0):

there 's a constructor for Mat(and an assignment operator, too), that takes a vector as input, so the same applies to rows of a Mat ( which are Mat's again )

```
Mat big(5,5,CV_32S); // 5x5, 1channel, int mat
vector<int> vec(5); vec[0]=1; vec[2] = 17; vec[4]=13;  // make a row vec
```

<strike>big.row(1) = vec; // careful, does not work for col(), since that returns a copy</strike>

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 17 0 13
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

i was wrong here, sorry. both row() and col() make a copy of the original data, so assigning to that is useless.